# Merge similar records in MySQL (python & sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, similarity

I've an huge database table, composed by Music genres.
There're almost 35000 records, most of them are mainly expressing the same genre, for example:

```
+-----------+ 
| Name      |
+-----------+
| "Dubstep" |
| Dub Step  |
| Dubstep   |
| dub-step  |
| dubstep   |
+-----------+
```

can all be reduced to one unique genre, we simply could call it "dubstep".

So I'd want to achieve a cleaner dataset, but I'd like to hear some suggestions,
how do I know if "dub step" and "dubstep" are expressing the same meaning?

Note that I'm using Python and SQLAlchemy. 
I'm by no meaning a very SQL expert.

Comment: If you're asking how to clean up your dataset, that really depends on what you plan on doing. Is this the "genre" table or the "album" table? Will users continue adding new varieties of "Dubstep"? What about the typo "dbustep?" There isn't a simple solution to this, and it depends on what you're trying to do with the data to even get started answering this question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After some research, I'm now thinking about adopting an algorithm like **dice coefficient** to calculate how far terms are distants. Next, I'd then keep a reference to the stripped-out genre record's id and then update all old reference other models have (tracks, albums, etc.) to the correct and (hopefully) unique one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to canonize the therms by lower-casing everything then strip out non alphanumeric chars as space, dash, etc. This will solve some if not most of the differences while creating the least amounts of false positives.

Another option to be done stand alone or combined with the first is to use the Levenshtein Distance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance, and group words with minimal distances.

Note that: you should first see how much is actually "most of them" by seeing how many cases will be cleaned up by using the first solution, then try gradually filtering them out until you hit the corner cases which most probable are few and can be manually aided.

For actually implementing this, I would transfer everything in a sqlite database, then write (or experiment with) a collation function in python and apply it. Example: http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html search for create_collation.